# Adjoint actions in abstract tensor categories

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory

Say we have a Lie group $G$. The category of (finite, complex) representations $\mathsf{Rep}\,G$ contains the adjoint representation $\mathfrak{g}$ which has many special properties. For instance $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie algebra internal to the category. Furthermore, there is a natural transformation
$$\eta: (\mathfrak{g}\otimes -)\rightarrow\text{id}_{\mathsf{Rep}\,G}$$
which satisfies
$$\eta_{\mathbf a\otimes\mathbf b} = \eta_{\mathbf a}\otimes 1_{\mathbf b}+(1_{\mathbf a}\otimes\eta_{\bf b})\circ(\beta_{\mathfrak g,\mathbf a}\otimes 1_{\mathbf b})$$
where $\beta$ is the braiding, which gives the action of the adjoint on a representation.

I am interested in the generalization of the adjoint representation to abstract symmetric tensor categories. Have such categories been considered in the literature, and if so where can I find out more?

Comment: I think we can find a canonical analogue of $\mathfrak{g}$ in suitably nice symmetric monoidal categories by taking the Hochschild homology of the unit in a suitable sense; see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3636. The idea is that we can think of $\text{Rep}(G)$ as sheaves on $BG$ and $\mathfrak{g} \in \text{Rep}(G)$ as a shifted version of the tangent bundle of $BG$, which in nice cases is accessible from Hochschild homology by a generalized Hochschild-Kostant-Rosenberg theorem.